# "Show All Day area" does nothing in Silverlight telerik RadScheduleView

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, telerik, telerik-scheduler

I am using Telerik silverlight RadScheduler with Silverlight. It seems "Show All Day area" property of ViewDefinition is not working.I have enabled "ShowAllDayArea" to "true" it in ViewDefintion .The "IsAllDayEvent" property in appointments are checked against the Start date and  the End Date in View Model. But all day events are not showing in the top of the scheduler .Could any one help on this ?

### Product Version

2014.3.1202.1050

### Xaml Schedule View

```
<telerik:RadScheduleView
        Name="radScheduleDetails"            
        NavigationHeaderVisibility="Collapsed"
        ActiveViewDefinitionIndex="{Binding ActiveViewDefinitionIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
        DragVisualTemplate="{StaticResource DragVisualContentTemplate}"
        DragDropHighlightStyle="{StaticResource CustomDragDropHighlightStyle}"
        EditAppointmentDialogStyle="{StaticResource CustomEditAppointmentDialogStyle}"              
        ToolTipTemplate="{StaticResource AppointmentToolTipTemplate}"
        AppointmentsSource="{Binding Appointments}"                
        SelectedAppointment="{Binding SelectedAppointment, Mode=TwoWay}"
        AppointmentSelectionChanged="radScheduleDetails_AppointmentSelectionChanged"
        AppointmentItemContentTemplate="{StaticResource templateCalAppointment}"
        ShowDialog="RadScheduleDetails_OnShowDialog"              
        DialogClosing="RadScheduleDetails_OnDialogClosing"
        AppointmentEdited="RadScheduleView_AppointmentEdited"
        GroupDescriptionsSource="{Binding GroupDescriptions,Mode=TwoWay}"
        ResourceTypesSource="{Binding ResourceTypes,Mode=TwoWay}"
        VisibleRangeChangedCommand="{Binding VisibleDateRangeChanged}"
        VisibleRangeChangedCommandParameter="{Binding VisibleRange,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        CurrentDate="{Binding ViewCurrentDate,Mode=TwoWay}"                         
        SpecialSlotsSource="{Binding WorkingHours}"
        TimeRulerItemStyleSelector="{StaticResource TimeRulerItemStyleSelector}"      
        GroupHeaderStyleSelector="{StaticResource GroupHeaderItemSelector}"
        MinTimeRulerExtent="600" MaxTimeRulerExtent="10000"   FirstVisibleTime="07:30"
        AppointmentEditing="radScheduleDetails_AppointmentEditing" >

                <telerik:DayViewDefinition
                    x:Name="DayViewDefination"
                                           EnableSmallAppointmentRendering="True"                                        
                                           ShowWeekGroupHeaders="False"                                             
                                           GroupFilter="{Binding GroupFilter}"                                              
                                           MinTimeRulerExtent="1600"         
                                           MaxTimeRulerExtent="1600"                                                 
                       MajorTickLength="1h"
                       MinorTickLength="30min"      
                                           ShowTimeRuler="True"   
                                           ShowAllDayArea="True"
                                                />
```